# How do I open a modal from normal navigator stacks?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I need to open and close a modal from a 'normal'/card flow navigator. I've split up the tabs, logged out (auth flow) and main screen flow in seperate navigators. Also tried to seperate the modal navigators in their own stack above the others.

These are pretty basic app flow requirements, surprised the docs doesn't have any examples

```
const AuthScreen = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Landing: { screen: Landing },
        Login: { screen: Login },
        Signup: { screen: Signup },
        Terms: { screen: Terms }
    },
    {
        mode: "modal"
    }
);

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: Home },
        Suppliers: { screen: Suppliers },
        Shortlist: { screen: Shortlist },
        "To-Do": { screen: ToDo },
        Inspiration: { screen: Inspiration }
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;

                if (routeName == "Home") {
                    return <Image source={require("../assets/icons/home.png")} />;
                } else if (routeName == "Suppliers") {
                    return <Image source={require("../assets/icons/suppliers.png")} />;
                } else if (routeName == "Shortlist") {
                    return <Image source={require("../assets/icons/shortlist.png")} />;
                } else if (routeName == "To-Do") {
                    return <Image source={require("../assets/icons/todo.png")} />;
                } else if (routeName == "Inspiration") {
                    return <Image source={require("../assets/icons/inspiration.png")} />;
                }
            }
        }),
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: "#F19B75",
            inactiveTintColor: "#4A4A4A",
            style: {
                backgroundColor: "white",
                elevation: 0,
                borderTopWidth: 0
            },
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 10,
                fontFamily: "Lato-Light"
            }
        }
    }
);

const ModalsStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        FilterSearch: {
            screen: FilterSearch
        },
        LocationSearch: {
            screen: LocationSearch
        }
    },
    {
        mode: "modal",
        navigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#fff", elevation: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 },
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: "normal",
                fontFamily: "Lora",
                fontSize: 18
            }
        }
    }
);

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Tabs: TabNavigator,
        CategoryItem: {
            screen: CategoryItem
        },
        SupplierProfile: {
            screen: SupplierProfile
        }
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "white",
                borderBottomWidth: 0,
                elevation: 0
            }
        },
        cardStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "white"
        },
        headerTransitionPreset: "uikit"
    }
);

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Auth: AuthScreen,
    Home: HomeStack
});
```

So I want to be able to open FilterSearch from CategoryItem screen.

Comment: Currently, I'm using `DrawerNavigator`. `DrawerNavigator` has the `home` is `StackNavigator` with `mode: 'modal'`,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add it also in the `HomeStack`?

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Tabs: TabNavigator,
    CategoryItem: {
      screen: CategoryItem
    },
    SupplierProfile: {
      screen: SupplierProfile
    },
    FilterSearch: {
      screen: FilterSearch,
      mode: 'modal',
      navigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff', elevation: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 },
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'normal',
          fontFamily: 'Lora',
          fontSize: 18
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
        elevation: 0
      }
    },
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    headerTransitionPreset: 'uikit'
  }
);
```